# ImageIO.read closes inputs stream

Tags: java, image, stream

I write images and other data to binary file. When I read image via ImageIO.read(InputStream) from that file, it reads image, it is ok, but method closes given input stream and I cant proceed to read other data.

1. Why so it is made?
2. Then how read image without closing stream?

**EDIT**: It is simple code that writes image and string after into file:

```
File f = new File("test.bin");
if(f.exists())
f.delete();
f.createNewFile();
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("test.jpg"));
ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", os);
os.writeUTF("test string after image");
os.close();
```

And code that reads all:

```
DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(is);
String s = is.readUTF(); // on this line EOFException occurs
System.out.println(s);
```

NetBeans output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:340)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:589)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
at mediamanager.Main.test(Main.java:105)
at mediamanager.Main.main(Main.java:44)
```

May be I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Where I was when I saw EOFException? It's just read all bytes till the end, it doesn't close input stream!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quote from the documentation of [ImageIO.read(InputStream)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.InputStream%29)

> This method *does not* close the provided InputStream after the read operation has completed; it is the responsibility of the caller to close the stream, if desired.

Emphasis *not* mine.

The problem is elsewhere. Probably in your code.

Comment: Yes, I read it. But in my code reading of next bytes returns -1 and further EOFException. I try to make simple code and post here if I will reproduce this error.

Comment: Very strange. I did a little experiment, and it seems like the ImageIO.read() method reads more bytes than strictly necessary to read the image. Fo example, if I write 10,000 bytes after the image, I can only read 7998 bytes after reading the image. I have no idea how to fix that except by knowing the size (N) of each image, read N bytes in a byte array, and reading the image from this byte array.

Comment: And it also seems like you could have had the inverse bug: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6687964

Comment: So, this is a bug... Well, remains to write image length and read it into separate stream. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possible causes of such behaviour:

1. Image reader use buffer to read data from the stream to improve performance. So it reads more data from the stream.
2. Also image reader could try to read EXIF for already parsed image. Such information usually appended at the end of file to avoid full file rewriting when you are just adding a couple of piece of information about the image.

Try `ImageIO.setUseCash(false)` it could help.

Comment: I propose better solution for this storage.

Comment: First of all you should define image data size before write it. [Size][Image][Text].

To read exact number of bytes from the stream you should weite your own InputStream extension (I have not found any applicable in java.io).
Something like following:
`
    private int sizeLeft;

    @Override int read() {

        if (sizeLeft < 0) return -1;

        int readed = origin.read();

        if (readed != -1) sizeLeft--;

        return readed;

    }
`


and so on. Do the same for available and rest 'read' methods.

Comment: I tried to write more data after writing string and outputs position in input stream. Yes, reader reads stream to the end, but I've changed format to PNG, which hasn't EXIF.